# over PARTITION BY query throws error

Tags: teradata

This query should work IMHO:

```
SELECT        
    Year                             
    ,Month 
    ,SUM(SomeFactMeasure) OVER (PARTITION BY Year BY Month) AS BigSum
    ,SUM(SomeFactMeasure) AS SmallSum 
FROM SomeTable
GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

Unfortunately, I am getting:

```
SELECTED NON-AGGREGATE VALUES MUST BE PART OF THE ASSOCIATED GROUP
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OLAP-functions are calculated *after* aggregation, there's no more detail `SomeFactMeasure` to be summed in the Group Sum.

You need to apply the funtion on the aggregated result, either Standard SQL compliant `SUM(SUM(SomeFactMeasure)) OVER` or Teradata's reuse of the alias `SUM(SmallSum) OVER`.